# Select by color doesn't select all the pixels of the desired color in a python-fu script

Tags: gimp, python-fu

I am writing a python-fu script for gimp that should have a line where it select all pixels of certain color. To do this, I added the line:

```
    gimp.pdb.gimp_by_color_select(clipLayer,(white_level,white_level,white_level),0,CHANNEL_OP_REPLACE,TRUE,FALSE,0,TRUE)
```

where `cliLayer` is the layer I'm working on (top layer) and white_level is an input parameter.

When I give the value manually (e.g replacing the `(white_level,white_level,white_level)` with `(136,136,136)`), the selection is carried properly, why is that so?

Answer (score 1):

Adding

```
white_level = int(white_level)
```

at the beginning of the function solve this.